# Loop in Java not working

Tags: java, loops

I can't seem to figure out why this loop doesn't work. Every time I hit cancel the loop stops and the code keeps running.

```
boolean sellPass = false;
while(!sellPass){
    Object[] fields = {"Temperature: " + temperature + " Forecast: " + weather[randomWeather] + "\nPrice per Cup in Cents", fieldCup,"Lemons per Pitcher", fieldLemons,"Sugar per Pitcher", fieldSugar, "Ice per Cup", fieldIce};

    int responsePitcher = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,fields,"Selling Price",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if(responsePitcher == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
        int stopGame = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you wish to cancel the game? All progress will be lost","",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(stopGame == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
            sellPass = false;
        }
    }
    while(!validateInt(fieldCup.getText()) || !validateInt(fieldLemons.getText()) || !validateInt(fieldSugar.getText()) || !validateInt(fieldIce.getText())){

        if(responsePitcher == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
            int stopGame = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you wish to cancel the game? All progress will be lost","",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(stopGame == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                System.exit(0);
            }else{
                sellPass = false;
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"One of the inputs is incorrect! try Again","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        responsePitcher = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,fields,"Price",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }

    //convert string to double and int 
    priceCup = Double.parseDouble(fieldCup.getText()) / 100;
    lemonsPitcher = Integer.parseInt(fieldLemons.getText());
    sugarPitcher = Integer.parseInt(fieldSugar.getText());
    iceCup = Integer.parseInt(fieldIce.getText());

    if(lemonsPitcher > lemons || sugarPitcher > sugar || iceCup > ice){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ops! it looks like you don't have enough ingredients to make that lemonade","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }else{
        sellPass = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you set `fieldCup` value?

Comment: so i assumed that when you cancel, the sellPass get set to false?

Comment: it is supposed to get set to false but the the loop stops. fieldCup is set earlier in the code

Comment: ok I figured out the cancel code should go last, after sellPass is set to true so that it can be overwritten